# What is Tsirelson's bound for the original bell's inequality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

As its well known, quantum correlations break Bell's inequalities only to a certain limit called the [Tsirelson's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsirelson%27s_bound). The bound was written for the [CHSH inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality).

My question is what is the Tsirelson bound for the original case that Bell dealt with in his article, and how it is proven.

Answer (score 2):

The folklore says the upper bound is 3/2 but I don't remember a reference. I am going to reproduce some old notes of mine demonstrating that bound.

First, Bell's original inequality is eqn (15) of [1]:

$$1+P(\vec{b},\vec{c})\ge|P(\vec{a},\vec{b})-P(\vec{a},\vec{c})|,$$

where $a,b,c$ are unit vectors. The associated quantum prediction is obtained by using eqn (3) which states that

$$P(\vec{x},\vec{y})=-\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}.$$

So the quantum version of the inequality can be written

$$\underbrace{|\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}-\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}|+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}}_{\displaystyle R}\le 1.$$

Your question would then be how badly $R$ can violate that upper bound of 1. By a suitable choice of basis, we can always write

$$\begin{align}
\vec{c}&=(\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi,0),\\
\vec{b}&=(\cos\varphi,-\sin\varphi,0),\\
\vec{a}&=(\cos\phi\sin\theta,\sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\theta),
\end{align}$$

with $\varphi,\phi\in[0,2\pi]$ and $\theta\in[0,\pi]$.

Then

$$\begin{align}
\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}&=\cos(\phi+\varphi)\sin\theta,\\
\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}&=\cos(\phi-\varphi)\sin\theta,\\
\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}&=\cos^2\varphi-\sin^2\varphi,
\end{align}$$

and

$$R=2|\sin\varphi\sin\phi\sin\theta|+1-2\sin^2\varphi.$$

This is a second-order polynomial in $|\sin\varphi|$ whose maximum is reached for $|\sin\varphi|=\frac{1}{2}|\sin\phi\sin\theta|$ and the maximum value is $\frac{1}{2}|\sin\phi\sin\theta|+1.$
This latter bound is then maximum for $\phi=\theta=\pi/2$ and the maximum value is $3/2$. It is therefore reached for $\varphi=\pi/4$.

[1] John S. Bell. On the Einstein Podolsky Rosen paradox. Physics, 1(3):195–200, 1964. ([pdf](https://cds.cern.ch/record/111654/files/vol1p195-200_001.pdf))

Comment: Thank you, very interesting.
But the proof is only for the specific case of spin 1/2
It is still interesting to know what is the Tsirelson's bound for quantum correlations in general. Will it always be 1.5 ??(The known Tsirelson's bound for  CHSH inequality was originally shown for any quantum correlations)

Comment: I mean, is there any general proof that does not use spin properties, but is generally correct for any three quantum variables (each of which can have the value 1 or minus 1) ??

Comment: The CHSH inequality only works for observables with $\pm 1$ outcomes as far as I know, and since the upper bound is $2\sqrt{2}$, as opposed to $3/2$ for Bell's original one, there is clearly no universal value valid for any  inequality. I really don't see how such an universal value could hold without some constraints on how to build such inequalities. In any case, your question only asked about the original Bell's inequality, not about a general case.

Comment: I did not mean universal value valid for any inequality. But a value that would fit to the same inequality (like  the original Bell's inequality) but for different quantum variables, rather than the spin. Instead of trying to explain exactly what I am referring to, I will give an example.  see the proof that Tsirelson himself brings in his article. He sets out a general proof for CHSH inequality but does not talk about spins.

Comment: Just to be sure: you refer to "B. S. Cirel’son. Quantum generalizations of bell’s inequality. Letters in Mathematical Physics, 4:93–100, 1980.", don't you? If so, Tsirelson considers operators "having their spectra consisting of two points {-1;1}" (paragraph just before theorem 1). Each of the $A_k$ and $B_l$ he considers can therefore be seen as the component of a spin along a different direction for each $k$ and $l$.

Comment: But, maybe I see your point: I followed Bell's premise of a singlet state for which the expectation value of $\vec{\sigma}_1\cdot\vec{a}\ \vec{\sigma}_2\cdot\vec{b}$ is $-\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$. Do you then seek an upper-bound valid for any expectation value? The CHSH upper bound of $2\sqrt{2}$ is of this kind, valid for any quantum state.

Comment: To clarify what I mean, I would replace $P(\vec{a},\vec{b})$ by $\langle \psi | A(\vec{a})B(\vec{b}) | \psi \rangle$ where $\psi$ can be any quantum state.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. That you used the fact that the expectation value is −a*b.  All your calculations with the cosines and sinuses are based on this.  I seek an upper-bound valid for any expectation value. But probably for a general proof that is correct for any quantum state, another proof must be formulated.

Comment: Ok, sorry to have missed your point then. The most straightforward demonstration for CHSH is very specific to the form of the inequality, so that's a dead end for Bell's one, I think. But I can introduce make use of a Schmidt decomposition of an arbitrary $|\psi\rangle$ and work my way from there. I'll give it a go.

Comment: You have nothing to be sorry for, it was interesting to see your calculation anyway. If you have proof of what I'm looking for of course I'd love to see. (By the way, I asked Tsirelson himself this question, and he answered that CHSH inequality is more fundamental, and Bell's original inequality is interesting only for historical reasons, so he is not so interested in finding the limit to Bell's inequality .Still, I'm interested in it ...)

Comment: Well, yes, sure, he's got a point, but that can still be a fun exercise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Tsirelson's bound for CHSH works only with matrix sum. If one uses Kronecker sum instead then the eigenvalues are -4,-2,0,2,4. So the average of CHSH can reach 4 in tensor quantum mechanics.